# PowerShell cannot use New-PSSessions right after Invoke-CimMethod (The runspace state is not valid for this operation)

Tags: powershell

The two code below works independently, however, they cannot work in the same script. I really need help, there's got to be something incompatible.

The first part of my script uses Invoke-CimMethod to Enable-PSRemoting, and it works.

**Variables**

```
$hostname = 'PC1'
$Session = New-PSSession $hostname
$DestinationPath = "C:\windows\temp"
```

**Part 1**

```
$SessionArgs = @{
     ComputerName  = $hostname
     Credential    = $credential
     SessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
 }
 $MethodArgs = @{
     ClassName     = 'Win32_Process'
     MethodName    = 'Create'
     CimSession    = New-CimSession @SessionArgs
     Arguments     = @{
         CommandLine = "powershell Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList 'Enable-PSRemoting -Force'"
     }
 }

Invoke-CimMethod @MethodArgs
```

The second part of my code works if the first part above is not present. It is to create a TEMP folder, and then copy an entire folder into TEMP.

**Part 2**

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($Destination) New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}  -ArgumentList $DestinationPath

Copy-Item -Path "\\shared\folder\foo\bar" -ToSession $Session -Destination "C:\windows\temp\" -recurse -force
```

**Error**

```
Copy-Item : The runspace state is not valid for this operation.
```

What's weird is I've inserted the Invoke-CimMethod to many other scripts that does similar things and it works fine, like for example

**Example of it working**

```
$env:hostname
$env:process

$SessionArgs = @{
     ComputerName  = $env:hostname
     Credential    = $credential
     SessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
 }
 $MethodArgs = @{
     ClassName     = 'Win32_Process'
     MethodName    = 'Create'
     CimSession    = New-CimSession @SessionArgs
     Arguments     = @{
         CommandLine = "powershell Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList 'Enable-PSRemoting -Force'"
     }
 }

 Invoke-CimMethod @MethodArgs

$session = New-PSSession $env:hostname

ipconfig
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {param($process) Stop-Process -ProcessName $process -Force} -ArgumentList $env:process

$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

Please help! I've tried everything, I even tried Get-CimSession | Remove-CimSession but that didn't work. Why is it incompatible?

Comment: You only need to enable psremoting once. Why would you need to run it every script?

Comment: The GPO resets the computers in our environment to not allow Enable-PSRemoting.

Comment: That’s what should be fixed then, not your script.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by adding another $Session = New-PSSession $hostname variable right before Invoke-Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by putting the variable

```
$Session = New-PSSession $hostname
```

right before `Invoke-Command` (rather than at the top of the script), because I think when I sent `Enable-PSRemoting` it resets the connection.

Comment: That makes sense, though if PowerShell remoting wasn't enabled until after the CIM-based `Enable-PSRemoting` call, I would have expected a prior`New-PSSession $hostname` to _fail_. Conversely, if it doesn't fail, you probably don't need a remote `Enable-PSRemoting` call.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { New-Item -Path $using:DestinationPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Please also consider adding an explanation to your answer, because it is unclear how it addresses the OP's problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).